# If I have a method which returns a distinct list should I make it return ISet<T> rather than IEnumerable<T>

Tags: .net, set

I have a method which selects a distinct collection of objects, adds them to a list and then returns the list.

Initially the method returned IEnumerable but as it returns a distinct collection I could add the distinct objects to a hashset and return ISet instead.

I appreciate that ISet makes the returned object modifiable (consumers could Add() to it) but I'm returning a new list anyway so I don't think this affects me, as  why do I care what the consumers do with the collection once they have it?

The question is, should I do this?  Or should I just return IEnumerable and be happy that it only contains distinct elements (which is currently guaranteed by a test)

Comment: _"I have a method ..."_ then show it since it might be helpful.

Comment: this depends a lot on context. Unless there's a good reason to choose `ISet<T>`, I'd probably just return `IEnumerable<T>` and **mention** that the elements are unique...

Comment: for context, a bug was discovered because the method wasn't returning distinct elements.  A test was added and Distinct() was called on the linq statement, but it made me think that maybe it would be better to return a set and make this explict

Comment: @TimSchmelter the method just returns the result of ToList() on a linq statement on some domain specific datasource, I'm not sure seeing that would help...

Comment: The list must be unique (not just happens to be unique) or it can throw an error and you are asking if you should make that explicit?

Comment: If you're not going to use a set, at the very least you should have a post condition that checks your list for distinct... At which point I'd think it would just be easier to return a set.  The question should be asked: will modifying the call signature at this point cause a new set of problems for whoever consumes your method?

Comment: @Blam I didn't say it throws an error, it just produces the wrong output.  This can be fixed by making the IEnumerable that is returned contain only unique elements, or the downstream processes could filter for unique elements.  Making it explicit here using ISet means that the downstream processes know they don't have to perform the redundant filter.

Comment: @rie819 a post condition to the call to 'Distinct' making sure that the result is a distinct set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ever, with design, you have contradictory requirements at play here. The art of good design is choosing the best balance between these requirements for the product you are creating.

One principal of interface design is that you consider the interface to be a contract or promise. Its obvious that, the less prescriptive a promise or contract is, the easier it is to keep. So, a return type of `IEnumerable<T>` means you are promising to return only a sequence of things. A "thighter" or more derived type would be more prescriptive and, a harder promise to keep.

Reflectively, if you are doing work in your function to ensure that a return type is more dervied, then it seems wasteful to abandon that work by returning the less perscriptive parent type. If you already have an `ISet<T>`, defining a set of things, be explicit, return that and save the caller the work of the distinct check.

In general, there is no simple answer, the right answer depends on the caller and your system. We have no knowledge of the caller in the general case. In the absence of evidence, we must assume nothing and take the tangible benefit of the weaker promise. So, in general, go with `IEnumerable<T>` it gives you greater flexibility in the furture with no known cost now.

In the specific case, where we know the caller will benefit from the return of a set. This is you case where a bug is raised on the distinctness of the sequence. It makes sense to be explicit and return an `ISet<T>`, this will help prevent duplication of the distinct check. To add a caveat, this only makes sense if the data will be distinct for every possible call. You must ensure you will keep the promise for all callers, not just those who have raised the bug.

Answer (score 0):

One why to look at your problem is "by example" in the case where a method returns a sequence of unique elements what should the return type be?

The BCL include such a method (which you state you are using) namely `Enumerable.Distinct<T>`

The return type of that method is IEnumerable. So why go with a type that does not in it self project all the promises the implementation will keep? I can see two arguments

- It's obvious from the name and intention of the method
- The IEnumerable contract is easier to fulfill that say ISet and will in most cases provide what's need by the consumer and in those cases where it's not enough the consumer can create the ISet. This why the cost is only needed when the value is also gained.

Would an interface IDistinctEnumerable change any of that? the only information that interface provide is in the name. The type system can encure that the elements in the sequence at runtime are unique but since it's just in the name that is essentially the same argument I used for Distinct.
If when seen from the outside it's expected by the method to return a set, then it's likely that this will stay so for ever and it might be worth it to then return a set. However there's a difference between a sequence of unique elements and a set.

Comment: does Distinct() not return IEnumerable so that delayed execution can be supported, as if ISet was returned we would need to create an implementation to return, thus forcing the expression tree to be evaluated?

Comment: @SamHolder nothing stopping you from having a lazily evaluated implementation of what ever interface Distinct or create another interface if those already created does not meet the needs. My point is they decided **not** to